# Is this safe: with open('test_file', 'w') as f: os.remove('test_file')?

Tags: python, io

I executed this code in Python, expecting to get some type of error:

```
with open('test_file', 'w') as f:
    os.remove('test_file')
```

but I did not get any error. When the `with` scope exits, the open stream gets closed. But I thought that would be illegal if the file was removed.

So why I don't get an error here?

Btw I am using Python 2.7. Is this different in Python 3?

I am using Linux. But I am interested in what would happen in Windows too.

Comment: Most operating systems will remove the link from the directory entry, but won't free the space until all open file descriptors for that file are closed. So you can open a file for reading/writing, but have it be removed after being opened and your program won't know the difference.

Comment: This would completely depend on the operating system.Some allow an open file to be deleted and some do not (by default).

Comment: What OS are you on? Unix lets you remove open files. Removing a file is really just removing its directory entry; the file will stick around if anyone has it open or if it has other directory entries (which is possible).

Comment: The built-in [`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) actually relies on this where possible, to make sure temporary files disappear as soon as you're done with them.

Comment: @user2357112 Not just when you are done with them, but before you even *start* writing to it, so that another process can't open it as well to see what you are writing.

Comment: @user2357112 See edit.

Comment: @becko Windows does not like this and throws a `WindowsError` exception stating that "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: @chepner: Also true, for a different sense of the word "disappear".